# How to create and name an Excel Sheet referencing a cell in the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to round out a rather large macro by copy and pasting the newly parsed data into a newly created sheet that is named with the date, which I am storing in cell B2 in the data insert sheet.  So put most simply, I want to create a new sheet and name it with the contents (a date) in cell B2 located in a different sheet.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Q" & lastRow).Select
Selection.Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Trade_Data_Insert).Range("B2")
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697706/how-to-add-a-named-sheet-at-the-end-of-all-excel-sheets)?

Comment: Yes I have.  That's a static name though and that's the part i'm having trouble eliminating.  The name needs to change as each new sheet is created with consecutive runs of the macro to what ever date is stored in B2 at the time of execution.

Comment: I don't think you understand it then XD You need to create an object then set the name. Edit: `Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name` has to change but `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Trade_Data_Insert).Range("B2")` does not, except I will qualify activeworkbook with another set object.

Comment: I'm not following it exactly.  I have experience with Swift so VBA is new to me.  Syntax is tripping me up.

Comment: It's a tad long to explain it fully and I am not exactly an expert :/ Perhaps read through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your macro to

```
Dim newSht As Worksheet
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Q" & lastRow).Select
Selection.Copy

Set newSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
newSht.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Trade_Data_Insert).Range("B2").Value
```

also... is `Trade_Data_Insert` a set variable? if its the name you need to put it in ""

Comment: Trade_Data_Insert is the name of the sheet being used to parse all the data and where the name of the worksheet is stored.  I am getting a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range when I run that code ^^  I reference trade data insert earlier in my code and it doesn't complain.

Comment: as already said: if your worksheed is named Trade_Data_Insert you need to put "" to make it work -> `...ok.Sheets("Trade_Data_Insert").Ran...`. pretty well shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479352/trying-to-reference-another-worksheet-in-active-workbook)